# Python: Compare a list and list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list as shown below:

```
z = [('Anna Smith', 'IN1'), ('John', 'IN2'), ('Matt Andrew', 'IN3'), ('Smith', 'IN4')]
```

And another list:

```
c = ['Anna Smith', 'John', 'Anna', 'Smith']
```

I want the below output:

```
o = ['Anna Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']
```

I have tried the below code:

```
for s, s_inc in z:
     for word in c:
          if word.lower() in s.lower():
                o.append("%s|%s"%(word, s_inc))
```

But the above gives me the output:

```
o = ['Anna Smith|IN1', 'Anna|IN1', 'Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']
```

How do I get what I want?

Comment: Why are you using lower-case membership tests when you appear to want to test for *whole* matches.

Comment: Additionally, you seem to want equality, not an in check - if word == s is the appropriate conditional

Comment: use a list comprehension : `['|'.join((i,t)) for i in c for k,t in z if k==i]
['Anna Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want an output for exact match when present...and partial match when not present.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is an elegant method for this type of filtering/list manipulation problems.

The comprehension consists of three parts:

-First the the result is constructed in a+'|'+b

-Secondly, a and b are assigned to the first and second element in each 2-tuple in list z

-Thirdly we filter on the condition that a must be a member of list c

```
print [a+'|'+b for a,b in z if a in c]

# Prints ['Anna Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']
```

Comment: Some (brief) explanation of how this works and what exactly it does could make the answer more helpful.

Comment: Point taken. Explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, it seems you are looking for an *exact match*, so just use `==` instead of `in`:

```
for s, s_inc in z:
     for word in c:
          if word == s:
                o.append("%s|%s"%(word, s_inc))
```

Or shorter, as a single list comprehension:

```
o = ["%s|%s"%(s, s_inc) for s, s_inc in z if s in c]
```

After this, `o` is `['Anna Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
z = [('Anna Smith', 'IN1'), ('John', 'IN2'), ('Matt Andrew', 'IN3'), ('Smith', 'IN4')]
c = set(['Anna Smith', 'John', 'Anna', 'Smith'])

o = [
    '|'.join([name, code]) for name, code in z if name in c   
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make `c` a *set*, for fast constant-time testing:

```
c_set = {w.lower() for w in c}
```

I lower-cased the words to make it easy to test for membership case-insensitively.

Then just use:

```
for s, s_inc in z:
    if s.lower() in c_set:
        o.append('|'.join([s, s_inc]))
```

or even:

```
o = ['|'.join([s, s_inc]) for s, s_inc in z if s.lower() in c_set]
```

to produce the whole list with a list comprehension.

Demo:

```
>>> z = [('Anna Smith', 'IN1'), ('John', 'IN2'), ('Matt Andrew', 'IN3'), ('Smith', 'IN4')]
>>> c = ['Anna Smith', 'John', 'Anna', 'Smith']
>>> c_set = {w.lower() for w in c}
>>> ['|'.join([s, s_inc]) for s, s_inc in z if s.lower() in c_set]
['Anna Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> z = [('Anna Smith', 'IN1'), ('John', 'IN2'), ('Matt Andrew', 'IN3'), ('Smith', 'IN4')]
>>> c = ['Anna Smith', 'John', 'Anna', 'Smith']
>>> ['|'.join([i,x[1]]) for x in z for i in c if x[0]==i]
['Anna Smith|IN1', 'John|IN2', 'Smith|IN4']
```